# How to run zxing in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, zxing, ios5

friends

Now, I upgraded xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0.

It looks nice, but problem is that I can't run my zxing sample app in xcode 4.2.

I always see following error message:

"unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7'".

How can I solve this prolblem?

Any good idea or experience?

Please help me...

Best regards and thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to reset the compiler to either llvm-gcc or clang (which is listed as "Apple default compiler" or something like that in Xcode 4.2). gcc (as both front and backend) is not supported in Xcode 4.2.

The original zxing Xcode projects set the compiler to gcc because llvm prior to Xcode 4.2 miscompiled zxing if you enabled optimizations. Xcode 4.2 fixed those issues so either compiler setting should work. (There are still issues with clang and C++ but those don't seem to affect zxing.)

Comment: If it works for you, you should accept the answer (click the outline checkmark to the left of the answer.)